# What kind of grammar it is in Android?

Tags: android

```
Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity01.this)
                .setTitle("Login hint")
                .setMessage("Here needs your login!")
                .setPositiveButton(...)
                .setNeutralButton(...
                ).create();
```

What kind of grammar it is? I cannot understand why those dots are one by one? And the `create()` is for `Builder()` or for `setNeutralButton()`?

Thanks!

Comment: (...) represent .setPositiveButton (int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)

Comment: This style of programming ('kind of grammar') is known as **fluent**.

Comment: Yep, and also known as **fluid** or **chainable**. Aside: it's not just Android uses this - or Java in fact - many OO languages (JavaScript, PHP and others) use this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Builder` is a static inner class of `AlertDialog`. Each call returns `this` allowing you to chain methods. Finally you call `create()` to create the actual dialog. This is basic Java and has little to do with Android, besides the fact that Android uses this pattern a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`setTitle`, `setMessage` are the methods of the DialogBox.

you can also write

```
Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity01.this);
dialog.setTitle("Login hint")
dialog.setMessage("Here needs your login!")
dialog.setPositiveButton(...)
dialog.setNeutralButton(...)
dialog .create();
```

if you want more clarification about this you can visit [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: Good! This is the way I can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

.setPositiveButton(...) refers you want to pass text to displayed and  write the logic for click events.

[Refer here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingButtons)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MyActivity.this.finish();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```